# Refactoring redundant loop logic

Tags: ruby

My code is supposed to take answers (true) from a QUIZ (MyQuiz) and compare them to the Root types. The Quiz Questions have types (Names) associated through RootProfile to them. For example,

```
question.root_profile.name
```

would return something like:

```
{question: "1", name: "ocean", ...}
```

I should know what type of answers I have as well.

```
answer.question.root_profile.name
```

When I get back all the true Answers from MyQuiz, I could have 10 Ocean 6 birds 3 tires. Then, based on that, I calculate the percentile of each against the whole quiz. If the quiz has 100 questions, it would calculate 10% ocean, 6% Birds, and 3% tires.

The code is as follows:

```
module RootServices
  class RootCount

    def initialize (my_quiz)
      @my_quiz = my_quiz
    end

    attr_reader :my_quiz

    def root_counts(root_profile)
      total = []
      all_answers.each do |answer|
        if answer.question.root_profile.name == root_profile.name
          total << answer
        end
      end

      total_percentage = (total.count.to_f / all_answers.count.to_f) * 100
      element = {root_profile_id: root_profile.id, root_profile: root_profile.name, total: total_percentage}
      return element
    end

    def root_branch
      root_branch_total = []

      # Pass root_profile object to root_counts and store in the root_branch_total array of hashes the returned element
      root_profiles.each do |root_profile|
        root_branch_total << root_counts(root_profile)
      end

      return root_branch_total
    end

    def root_profiles
      title = RootProfile.all
    end

    def all_answers
      all_answers = my_quiz.my_answers.where(answer: true)
    end

  end
end
```

It works, but it's a little over-complicated, and the loop seems to be redundant. I was wondering if there would be a more elegant way. My logic works, but my logs show queries from Answers = true (let's say my test has five true) with five queries for RootProfile and five queries for Question Nested. Here is a visual:

```
SELECT "my_answers".* FROM ...
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
SELECT "my_answers".* FROM ...
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"
  SELECT  "root_profiles".* FROM "root_profiles"
...
3x more
```

EDIT: ADDING THE REFACTORED CODE BELLOW

```
module RootServices
  class RootCount

    def initialize (my_quiz)
      @my_quiz = my_quiz
      @root_profiles = RootProfile.all
      @all_answers = @my_quiz.my_answers.where(answer: true)
    end    

    def root_branch
      root_profiles.map { |root_profile| root_counts(root_profile) }
    end

    private

      attr_reader :my_quiz, :root_profiles, :all_answers

      def root_counts(root_profile)
        answers = matching_answers(root_profile)
        {
          root_profile_id: root_profile.id,
          root_profile: root_profile.name,
          total: percentage_of_total(answers)
        }
      end

      def matching_answers(root_profile)
        all_answers.joins(question: :root_profile).where("root_profiles.name = ?", root_profile.name)
      end

      def percentage_of_total(answers)
        (answers.count.to_f / all_answers.count.to_f) * 100
      end

  end
end
```

Comment: Which method you want to refactor?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh root_counts. I believe(I might be wrong) I could, Get all my_answers where answer  = true find what RootProfile they belong too and and calculate the RootProfile percentage without so many queries. I looked into Looping through 2 arrays (one from answer.question.root_profile.name and the other from RootProfile.all) and adding to another array when they match

Comment: Here ia something I'm tackling right now. Method root_branch call root_counts from inside of a loop passing each of the elements. In root_counts everytime `answer.question.root_profile.name` is called it runs the query `SELECT * FROM "questions" WHERE id =`.

Comment: Can you try `@all_answers ||= my_quiz.my_answers.includes(question: :root_profile).where(answer: true)` and see if some of the queries go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, I think you might be missing a couple of core concepts in ruby - the most obvious being implicit returns - in the case of your code it means you don't need a `return` statement at the end of the method, and you don't need to assign to a local variable in the one-liners. Ruby is nice like that.

You could cut down on the queries by collecting all the names you're going to be comparing against into a single query, rather than repeatedly calling `answer.question.root_profile.name`. Furthermore, you should probably do the selection in SQL rather than immediately turning it into an array. I'll refactor a couple of your methods for you to provide an example of how you could do this better.. something like the following

```
def root_counts
  answers = matching_answers(root_profile)
  {
    root_profile_id: root_profile.id,
    root_profile: root_profile.name,
    total: percentage_of_total(answers)
  }
end

private

def root_profiles
  RootProfile.all
end

def percentage_of_total(answers)
  (answers.count.to_f / true_answers.count.to_f) * 100
end

def true_answers
  my_quiz.my_answers.where(answer: true)
end

def matching_answers(root_profile)
  true_answers
    .joins(:questions, :root_profiles)
    .where("root_profiles.name = ?", root_profile.name)
end
```

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do with your `root_branch` method, as from what I can see it is returning an array containing the combination of (1) *all* of the `RootProfile` objects in the database, and (2) a collection of hashes containing the percentage count for that `root_profile` (as returned by the `root_count` method). I reckon you should re-think the logic for this.

Also, I would probably consider putting `root_profiles` as an instance variable that you initialise with the class (with an `attr_reader` as well) - since it loads the entire `root_profiles` table, thus it would be better to only call it once

Comment: Thanks a lot. Back to my code for clarification on the implicit returns. I wouldn't need to put return in the root_counts but I would need in the root_branch right? Without the return in the root_branch that method would end with a block

Comment: yes that's right, because you want to return `root_branch_total` but you're building the array iteratively after this, you need to return it. However you still don't need to use the keyword `return` - ruby will automatically return the last assignment or variable that is referenced in the method, so simply putting `root_branch_total` at the end (without the `return`) will work fine

Comment: but also, you don't need to build the collection like that either, (i.e. there's no need to have another variable and push elements into it) - the `root_branch` method can be a one-liner if you do this:

`root_profiles.map { |root_profile| root_counts(root_profile) }`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I added the refactored code to the original post